# Decimal number from JSON truncated when read from Mapping Data Flow

Tags: azure-data-factory

When reading a decimal number from JSON data files using a Mapping Data Flow, the decimal digits are truncated.

```
[Source data]

{
    "value": 1123456789.12345678912345678912
}
```

In Data Factory, the source dataset is configured with no schema. The Mapping Data Flow projection defines a decimal data type with sufficient precision and scale.

```
[Mapping Data Flow script]

source(output(
        value as decimal(35,20)
    ),
...
```

However, when viewing the value in the 'Data preview' window, or reviewing pipeline output, the value is truncated.

```
[Output]

1123456789.12345670000000000000
```

This issue doesn't occur with other file formats, such as delimited text.

When previewing the data from the source dataset, the decimal digits are truncated in the same way. This occurs whether or not a schema is set. If a schema is set, the data type is `number` rather than decimal since it's JSON. [Mozilla Developer Network documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) calls out the varied number of decimal digits supported by browsers, so I wonder if this is down to the JSON parser being used.

Is this expected behaviour? Can Data Factory be configured to support a the full number of decimal places when working with JSON? Unfortunately this is calling into question whether it's viable to perform aggregate calculations in Data Factory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a same test as yours and got the same result as follows:

[image]

After I changed the soure data, I put double quotes on the value:
[image]

Then I use a `toDecimal(Value,35,20)` to convert the string type to decimal type:

[image]

It seems work well. So we can get conclusion:

- Don't let ADF do default data type conversion, it will truncate the length of the value.
- This issue doesn't occur with other file formats, such as delimited text. Because the default value is the string type.

Comment: @joseph-xu Thanks for confirming the issue that I've encountered. Imposing format constraints on the source system is an option though problematic in this instance. The [Schema drift in source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-schema-drift#schema-drift-in-source) documentation indicates the data should arrive as strings seeing a schema isn't defined - _'all newly detected columns, known as drifted columns, arrive as a string data type'_.

Comment: @Tom Yes, that's correct. By default it will arrive as a string data type, but ADF has done a forced type conversion resulting in loss of precision.So we need to prevent this default behavior.

Comment: @Tom If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Its common issue with JSON parser, FloatParseHandling setting is available in .net library but not in ADF.

FloatParseHandling can set to Decimal while parsing the file through .net.

Until the setting is made available in ADF need to try the workaround - using quotes ["] at both end to make the value string and get it converted after loading.